# How can I access the name of the label of the current bibitem?

Tags: cross-referencing, bibitem

I would like to use the name of the "current" bibitem (in the definition of a label, but actually I think that might be irrelevant). Consider what I do now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Define the label #1 to be #2 (so \ref{X} gives Y):
\def\LABEL#1#2{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
% Display \label{URL:#1} in tty font:
\def\URL#1{\texttt{\ref{URL:#1}}}   

\begin{document}

The URL of the Wikipedia article on ``plain text''~\cite{WP:plain} is \URL{WP:plain}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{WW}
% define and immediately use a label for the URL of a WP page
\def\WPURL#1#2{\LABEL{URL:#1}{https://en.wikipedia.org/\hspace{0pt}wiki/#2}\URL{#1}}

\bibitem{WP:plain} Wikipedia: ``Plain text''. Last accessed: ... URL:
\WPURL{WP:plain}{Plain\_text}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

It gives, as expected:

> The URL of the Wikipedia article on “plain text” [1] is `https://en.wikipedia.org/ wiki/Plain_text`.
>
> **References**
>
> [1] Wikipedia: “Plain text”. Last accessed: ... URL: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text`

I would like to have `\WPURL` require only one argument, the currently second parameter ("basename" of the URL), and infer the first parameter (here `WP:plain`, used for the URL label) from the current `\bibitem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `\bibitem` to save its argument for later usage in the same item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Define the label #1 to be #2 (so \ref{X} gives Y):
\newcommand{\LABEL}[2]{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\NewCommandCopy{\original@bibitem}{\bibitem}
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
  \def\@currentbiblabel{#1}%
  \original@bibitem{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\WPURL}[1]{%
  \LABEL{URL:\@currentbiblabel}{https://en.wikipedia.org/\hspace{0pt}wiki/#1}%
  \URL{\@currentbiblabel}%
}
% Display \label{URL:#1} in tty font:
\newcommand{\URL}[1]{\texttt{\ref{URL:#1}}}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The URL of the Wikipedia article on ``plain text''~\cite{WP:plain} is \URL{WP:plain}. 

The URL of the Wikipedia article on ``whatever''~\cite{WP:whatever} is \URL{WP:whatever}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{WW}
% define and immediately use a label for the URL of a WP page

\bibitem{WP:plain} Wikipedia: ``Plain text''. Last accessed: ... URL:
\WPURL{Plain\_text}

\bibitem{WP:whatever} Wikipedia: ``Whatever''. Last accessed: ... URL:
\WPURL{Whatever}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although somewhat "violent", that's a great idea I should have though of myself. I thought one should be able to fetch the name of the label in the place where \bibitem stores it, but now I realize that maybe it isn't stored anywhere but only used as name of the variable(s) where the actually displayed label (and other info: pageref...) is/are stored in. Then your solution is probably the best or maybe even only one.