# How can I use a label (produced by \ref) as URL in hyperref's \href?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

How can I use a label (the result of `\ref`) as first argument (URL) in a `\href` command?
I want to be able to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\def\URLcite#1#2{%\href{\ref{URL:#1}} % fatal error if not commented out
{#2}~\cite{#1}}

The \URLcite{WP:plain}{wikipedia page for ``plain text''} explains that ...

\begin{thebibliography}{WW}
\def\WPURL#1#2{\def\@currentlabel{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}\label{URL:#1}
Available at URL: %\href{\ref{URL:#1}} % fatal error if not commented out
{\texttt{\ref{URL:#1}}}}

\bibitem {WP:plain} Wikipedia: \emph{Plain text}. \WPURL{WP:plain}{Plain\_text}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Everything works as expected, except for the `\href` commands which unfortunately yield "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [...]." when they are not commented out (in both instances).
I also tried with `\protected@edef` and/or `\phantomsection` which I found elsewhere, but it didn't change anything.

For the second instance, within the `\bibitem` where the label {URL:...} is defined, I can use the workaround

```
\def\WPURL#1#2{\edef\tmp{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}
\edef\@currentlabel{\tmp}\label{URL:#1}
Available at URL: \url{\tmp}} %% or equivalenty \href{\tmp}{\tt\tmp}
```

Then again, `\ref{URL:WP:plain}` yields the expected result (identical to `\tmp` within the `\bibitem`), and within the \bibitem, the `\url` / `\href` command works as long as it is using `\tmp` instead of `\ref{URL:WP:plain}`.

However, I want to be able to be able to use the value of that label also in the main text.
I tried to copy it into a temp.variable also within the `\URLcite` command, with many `\expandafter` and `\edef`, but if I understand well the problem, it was impossible to remove the `\protect` which seems to be produced by the `\label` command.

Is is possible to use the value stored in a `\label` as URL (1st arg) in a `\href` command?

Comment: Can't you use a bib file and biblatex?

Comment: It should be `\begin{thebibliography}{<widest label of bib-items>}`. See, e.g., [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References) .

Comment: To answer your question, see the refcount package (also included in hyperref, but not documented).

Comment: @Ulrike: I can use bibtex but that seems irrelevant for the question: using a custom label in a `\hyperref` command in the main text? Of course I could just link to the References section and have the user go there and from there to the WP URL, but the Q is, as written in title, how can I use an URL defined through `\label` or equivalent in a `\hyperref` command? It is not a bibliography related question.

Comment: @Ulrich: oops, sorry, thanks for catching - that's a copy-paste error, correct in my original, I'll fix that because it distracts attention from the question...

Comment: @John: interesting - and challenging, to "see" something that is not documented... :-)

Comment: Hyperref re-defines many macros provided by other packages.  Consequently, if you load hyperref then you don't actually need to load these other packages.

Comment: I didn't suggested to use bibtex (and application) but  biblatex (a package). biblatex provides many ready made commands to get links and urls from citations. As John and Ulrich wrote you can retrieve your value from the label with refcount, but be aware that you can run into problems if your url contains special chars like `%` or `#`.

Comment: @Ulrike: oh sorry, it didn't see the `la` in biblatex. I may give it a look, but my question wasn't really about (bibliographic) references, but using custom labels ("content stored in elsewhere defined variables", actually) in hyperrefs. I figured that `refcount` isn't needed. Indeed, I'm aware of special characters and remember that during my trials escaping the `_`  as `\_` sometimes raised other errors (because `hyperref` has its own processing of URLs, I guess). I'm nicely surprised that it works here, finally. I hope for % or # it might work in a similar way (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a .bib-file and biblatex.

If you don't like to maintain two files containing source of input, you can maintain the .bib-file within the .tex-file by means of a `filecontents*`-environment, probably toggling the `filecontents*`-environment-options `overwrite=false`/`overwrite=true`.

If you absolutely don't like this, you probably can use the package [refcount](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)  for expandably extracting cross-referencing data with URL-arguments of `\href`-commands. Cross-referencing labels in any case are not defined during the first latex-run. Therefore I added some checking and default-handling of this situation. (A hyperlink to page 1 of the pdf-file itself instead of attempting creation of a hyperlink to an url which is unknown due to the cross-referencing-label whose referencing should deliver it being undefined.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand\URLcite[2]{%
  \refused{URL:#1}%
  \IfRefUndefinedBabel{URL:#1}{%
    \hyperlink{Doc-Start}%
  }{%
    \href{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{}}%
  }{#2}~\cite{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\WPURL[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@currentlabel{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}%
  \label{URL:#1}%
  \endgroup
  Available at URL: %
  \refused{URL:#1}%
  \IfRefUndefinedBabel{URL:#1}{%
    \hyperlink{Doc-Start}%
  }{%
    \href{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{}}%
  }%
  {\texttt{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{\textsf{??}}}}%
}% 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

The \URLcite{WP:plain}{wikipedia page for ``plain text''} explains that ...

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem {WP:plain}Wikipedia: \emph{Plain text}.\\ \WPURL{WP:plain}{Plain\_text}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Pdf-file after first LaTeX-run where cites and cross-referencing-labels are still undefined/unknown—also obey messages on the console and in the .log-file:

[image]

Pdf-file after subsequent LaTeX-run where cites and cross-referencing-labels are defined/known—still also obey messages on the console and in the .log-file ;-)   :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Slightly too much information here. I tried to make a minimal example. Mentioning bibtex deviates from the topic and problem which is to define a custom label in References and use it in `\hyperref` in the main text. Now I guess `\getrefbykeydefault` may be what I'm looking for, but I'll have to check. Also I'm surprised that there be no issue with `\_` vs `_` in the URL.

Comment: PS: I do have basic knowledge and know that I have to compile several passes to get labels right, the problem was that compilation aborted with "TeX capacity exceeded" and so no aux file is ever written.

Comment: Thank you again, your code mysteriously works out of the box! Unfortunately it's difficult to understand why, is it `\refused` or `\IfRefUndefinedBabel` ? therefore the "checking and default-handling of this situation" are probably crucial and not just esthetical to avoid error messages on the first compilation only. I suspected this because I saw "undefined \reserved@a" or the like in the logs but would never have found how to get rid of these.

Comment: Thank you again, your code works great and I could purge it from all that isn't required to verify that replacing `\ref{...}` in both instances by `\getrefbykeydefault{...}{}{}` is sufficient to have everything work like a charm! (I assume that the label which is undefined in the first run does not just cause a "??" to appear but produces a fatal error so the aux file can never be written.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrich's answer I was able to find the very answer to my question which I'll write down here for my own reference and for others who are looking for exactly this without distractions: The key and all that's needed to do the job is to replace the plain `\ref{...}` command by `\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{}` (which avoids abortion of the compilation due to the error resulting from the label that's undefined during the first run). No other package and command appears is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\URLcite[2]{\href{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{}}{#2}~\cite{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\WPURL[2]{{\def\@currentlabel{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#2}\label{URL:#1}}
 Available at URL: \href{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{}}{\texttt{\ref{URL:#1}}}}

\begin{document}

The \URLcite{WP:plain}{wikipedia page for ``plain text''} explains that ...

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem {WP:plain}Wikipedia: \emph{Plain text}. \WPURL{WP:plain}{Plain\_text}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

It should be obvious that it is completely irrelevant for the question that the label holding the URL is defined in a bibliography environment / "References" section. The point is, as the title of the question clearly states, to define an URL anywhere in the document and use it as first argument to a `\href` command anywhere else, in particular, prior to its definition.

See, however, [this somewhat related question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645813/how-can-i-access-the-name-of-the-label-of-the-current-bibitem) about how one can avoid to manually put/repeat the label of the bibitem (here: `{WP:plain}`) in the `\WPURL` command.

Comment: With your example in the first LaTeX-run I - as expected - get the confusing warning-messages `Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing link with empty target on input line 10.`  and `Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing link with empty target on input line 13.`  Besides this with your code in case of doing typos with cross-referencing-labels you are never informed about which cross-referencing-labels are undefined. That's why in my code I defaulted to hyperlinking to page 1 of the current document in case of the cross-referencing-label not being defined and why in my code `\refused` is applied.

Comment: As can easily be seen in the manual of the refcount-package, `\refused` checks whether a cross-referencing is defined/undefined. If it is undefined, messages in the .log-file and on the console are triggered, informing about that circumstance - this eases fixing the issue.

Comment: @ 9:29 : But you *always* get warnings resulting from undefined references on the first run, which disappear on the 2nd or 3rd run, as do the two "...Warning..." messages you mention. So I don't think such warnings appearing only in the first run are really irrelevant. But OK, one might avoid them alltogether by adding a '?' as default = 3rd argument of `\getrefbykeydefault`.

Comment: `\href{\getrefbykeydefault{URL:#1}{}{?}}{...}` in the first run produces a pdf-file containing a link to a file `?.pdf` or the like. Clicking the link yields behavior depending on the pdf-viewer and the computer-platform in use. That's another reason why I decided to catch this case by means of a hyperlink to the start of the document.

Comment: ok, but again, no-one looks at the result of the first run which is necessarily incorrect as soon as \ref or \cite is used. So isn't is even conceptually wrong to try to produce something (necessarily only partially) correct on the first run?

Comment: The intention is not producing something (partially) correct but is producing something where behavior is not all too unpredictable/all too dependent on the pdf-viewer. This might be of interest with things like AUCTeX where pdf-output is produced on the fly. While mentioning differences in the behavior of different solutions might make it easier for users to pick out what they like best, it is not worthwhile to indulge in persuasion, since with many aspects the handling is also a matter of taste and preference and thus subjective, and everyone has the freedom to design as they like.